# Ghidra wrong array size

Tags: decompilation, ghidra, decompile, decompiler

I'm new to the field, so it's probably a stupid question, but when I tried to decompile [this](https://2019shell1.picoctf.com/static/ae3e9fb0aa6dd438251939839a7a6f21/mystery) binary from picoCTF 2019 I got an array of size 4 (local_38) when looking at a [solution](https://github.com/Dvd848/CTFs/blob/master/2019_picoCTF/Investigative_Reversing_0.md) it should be of size 26.

Why is this happening? And what should I do to solve this if possible?

Here is the result of the decompling.

```
void main(void)

{
  FILE *__stream;
  FILE *__stream_00;
  size_t sVar1;
  long in_FS_OFFSET;
  int local_54;
  int local_50;
  char local_38 [4];
  char local_34;
  char local_33;
  char local_29;
  long local_10;

  local_10 = *(long *)(in_FS_OFFSET + 0x28);
  __stream = fopen("flag.txt","r");
  __stream_00 = fopen("mystery.png","a");
  if (__stream == (FILE *)0x0) {
    puts("No flag found, please make sure this is run on the server");
  }
  if (__stream_00 == (FILE *)0x0) {
    puts("mystery.png is missing, please run this on the server");
  }
  sVar1 = fread(local_38,0x1a,1,__stream);
  if ((int)sVar1 < 1) {
                    /* WARNING: Subroutine does not return */
    exit(0);
  }
  puts("at insert");
  fputc((int)local_38[0],__stream_00);
  fputc((int)local_38[1],__stream_00);
  fputc((int)local_38[2],__stream_00);
  fputc((int)local_38[3],__stream_00);
  fputc((int)local_34,__stream_00);
  fputc((int)local_33,__stream_00);
  local_54 = 6;
  while (local_54 < 0xf) {
    fputc((int)(char)(local_38[local_54] + '\x05'),__stream_00);
    local_54 = local_54 + 1;
  }
  fputc((int)(char)(local_29 + -3),__stream_00);
  local_50 = 0x10;
  while (local_50 < 0x1a) {
    fputc((int)local_38[local_50],__stream_00);
    local_50 = local_50 + 1;
  }
  fclose(__stream_00);
  fclose(__stream);
  if (local_10 != *(long *)(in_FS_OFFSET + 0x28)) {
                    /* WARNING: Subroutine does not return */
    __stack_chk_fail();
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Just change the type of this variable with CTRL+L key command.

Comment: Ok, but how can I imagine the size without knowing the solution?

Comment: `fread` second parameter has value of `0x1a`=`26` so the buffer need to be at least that big.